# Mutate not behaving as expected inside custom functions (variation)

Tags: r, tidyverse, function-call

My question is similar to Ariel Polani's and Tyler Law's, but in my case the `!!sym()` solution or the `!!` solution within `mutate()` does not work. Here is my code:

```
library(cansim)
library(tidyverse)
add_series <- function(vector_num,first_date,end_date,tseries) {
  tmp <- get_cansim_vector(vector_num,first_date,end_date)
  tseries <- mutate(tseries,!!sym(vector_num)=tmp$VALUE)
  return(tseries)
}
first_date <- as.Date("2011-01-01",format="%Y-%m-%d")
end_date <- as.Date("2019-06-01",format="%Y-%m-%d")
tseries <- data.frame(REF_DATE=seq(first_date,end_date,by="month"))
tseries <- add_series("v42170711",first_date,end_date,tseries)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are using `assignment` on string, use the `:=` and here we don't need `sym`

```
library(dplyr)
tseries <- tseries %>%
                 mutate(!!vector_num :=tmp$VALUE)
```

-full code

```
add_series <- function(vector_num,first_date,end_date,tseries) {
  tmp <- get_cansim_vector(vector_num,first_date,end_date)
  tseries %>%
       mutate(!! vector_num :=tmp$VALUE)

}

add_series("v42170711",first_date,end_date,tseries) %>%
     head
#    REF_DATE v42170711
#1 2011-01-01   1566882
#2 2011-02-01   1580492
#3 2011-03-01   1566209
#4 2011-04-01   1594096
#5 2011-05-01   1600677
#6 2011-06-01   1613907
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works for one series, but when I try it again for a second series v806086 it over-writes.    add_series("v806086",first_date,end_date,tseries) %>%
     headWhy would that be?

Comment: @PhilSmith  Because you are not assigning in place. `tseries <- add_series("v42170711",first_date,end_date,tseries)`